# What is Html.SnapbackLink? in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I found something like `<%=Html.SnapbackLink("linkText", "actionName") %><br /><br />` in my project code.It would be helpful if someone explains? what it is and when to use that?

Comment: I dont think there is any helper named above. It must be a custom extension made especially for your code, look into the files

Comment: Click on `SnapbackLink`, press F12.